# Add ngModel to input with dynamic html in typescript, Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to add a `td` dynamically in a html table, with an `input` inside, I want the input to have ngModel attribute and to be like this:

```
<td><input type="number" name="Price" [(ngModel)]="Product.Price"></td>
```

I added the `td` in my ts, like:

```
td = document.createElement('td');
input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
input.setAttribute('name', 'Price');
td.appendChild(input);
tr.appendChild(td);
```

now my question is, how to add ngModel to the dynamic td?

Comment: You can **not**. Rethink your code to create the inputs using *ngFor and an array: it's the "angular way"

Answer (score 1):

Two-way-bound `ngModel` is designed for template driven forms rather than the dynamic forms where you are adding the things dynamically.

If you already have access to the element dynamically, you can add `keyUp` event to it. So you can access the values typed in.

```
<td><input type="number" name="Price" [(ngModel)]="Product.Price"></td>
I added the td in my ts, like:

td = document.createElement('td');
input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'number');
input.setAttribute('name', 'Price');
td.appendChild(input);
tr.appendChild(td);

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      console.log(event);
})
```